# URL length and content optimised for SEO

Tags: web-development, search-engines, url, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best stucture of SEO friendly URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/what-is-the-best-stucture-of-seo-friendly-url)

I have done some reading on what URLS should look like for search engine optimisation, but I am curious to know how mine would like, I need some advice.

I have a tutorial website, and my categories is something like:

```
Web Development -> Client Side -> JavaScript
```

So if I have a tutorial called "What is JavaScript?", is it good to have a URL that looks something like:

```
www.MyWebsite.com/web-development/client-side/javascript/what-is-javascipt
```

Or would something like this be more appropriate:

```
www.MyWebsite.com/tutorials/what-is-javascipt
```

Just curious because I also read that it is wise to have keywords in your URLs.  Do I need to add the identifiers of each categories in the link as well, something like:

```
www.MyWebsite.com/1/web-development/5/client-side/15/javascript/100/what-is-javascipt

1 is the unique identifier (primary key) of category web development
5 is the unique identifier (primary key) of category client side
15 is the unique identifier (primary key) of category javascript
100 is the unique identifier (primary key) of tutorial what is javascript
```

Comment: Someone replied on this meesage.  The answer disappeared when this was closed.  Please return this answer ASAP.