# for a blog with posts and categories what are all the best ways to create user friendly and seo friendly urls

Tags: seo, url, user-friendly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best stucture of SEO friendly URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/what-is-the-best-stucture-of-seo-friendly-url)

I am creating a module in my website which displays ringtones.

It is like creating blog posts and categories, and it will also have categories (tags) and posts. (I am using category and tag interchangeably.)

I am using the following linking for this module:

1. `sitename.com/blog`
2. `sitename.com/blog/category/category-name-slug/` → will list all ringtones of that category/tag
3. `sitename.com/blog/title/name-slug-of-the-ringtone/` → will display the details and a download link

In every page, at the left I display the category/tag .

This is how I have formed the url structure.

Will it be user friendly, and (I hope so) will it be seo friendly as well?

Please hint if I am missing something or other ways to improve.

Meanwhile I am browsing the net to get more information on linking content (categorizing) and to find best ways for the user and search engine.