# Best practices with multiple categories/tags etc. on URL (SEO)

Tags: seo, google-search

I'm on the process of *building my eshop platform* and encountered a **SEO** issue.

My next step is to develop a *searching box*, where user searches the products of a specific category (say, *desktops*). This box will contain characteristics of the category *desktops*, for example, it will contain **RAM** and **CPU** for sure. *Notice* that in my searching box one will be able to **select more than one** categories.

My url (after rewrite) for *showing* products of a specific category is as this:

```
http://localhost/products/desktops
```

I know how to add another rewrite rule in .htaccess but i won't until i find out..

**what is the best practice of adding multiple categories/tags in url without inflate it and cause damage (etc. page ranking) rather gain something**.

For example, let's say someone wants to search *through desktops* and by (*CPU and RAM*)

Of course, the following patterns is non-acceptable, regarding variable size of input and known google dislike of many folders:

```
http://localhost/products/desktops/CPU/RAM/..
```

What about the following?

```
1. http://localhost/products/desktops/CPU-RAM
2. http://localhost/products/desktops/CPU|RAM
```

The *1* may seems nice but i learnt google is handling the hyphen (-) as words connector and these words are not connected?

The *2* is using the (|) pipe symbol since i learnt also google is using it to sort words of equal importance. I don't really if any of the above apply only to HTML content and/or not to URLs.

**How can i feed my URL so to include a number of categories, say about 5 max.** and if anyone knows how google handle such issue, etc. penalty or how searches/archive that stuff.
I don't really want to apply any *&filter_CPU=1&filter_RAM=1* thingy in the end and defeating the whole purpose.

**UPDATE:**
Since my time was in essence i already went for the following approach/URL rewrite:

```
http://localhost/products/desktops/search-for/Celeron|Pentium|4gb-ram...
```

, where `..` are a collection of category's attributes (etc. type of CPUs, size of memories etc. whatever characterizes them)

I thought *a lot* about the **delimiter** to use.
I can't use hyphens (-) since category attributes may already contain one and it's a rather typical character for such cases. I cant't use commas (,) or underscores (_) either for about the same reason and i don't like them (especially commas) on URL in general.

**I prefer something like a pipe but was wondering how bad this is for SEO? How google will index my information passed as ..*Celeron|4GB-RAM*.. Will it sort it out as 2 words (as they are?)** or i should do something else?

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board, too speficic and most likely duplicate due to the sheer amount of questions already on the site regarding url structure.

Comment: Additionally you may find [Hyphens or Underscores](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/374/urls-should-i-use-hyphens-underscores-or-plus-symbols) helpful because hyphens is preferred under `_` and `|`. And there's [plenty more on the site on topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo+url) which you should be able to establish which suits your site more.

Comment: Thanx for the link, but you pointed me to an even more broader question. Pls close my question.

Comment: @bybe: I don’t think that this question is a duplicate of [What is the best stucture of SEO friendly URL?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/what-is-the-best-stucture-of-seo-friendly-url): neither the question nor its answers are about vlzvl’s case where you have *several* tags in the path.